# An easy way to replace binary reference in the VS project with a project reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-power-tools

**Note:** system is poorly modularized, there is much coupling between components, and I am in no position to change that.

**Context** MS Visual Studio 2010 (Pro)

**Backstory:**
I have a solution that uses a web service. There is tight coupling between client [component] and said web service. When I work on the client I often need to tweak the web service. Both client and service have unreasonable number of [poorly modularized] projects. To make matter worse those web service projects have dependencies in the same manner on other web services and libraries. So that creating one solution will contain 200 projects, and will bring VS/R# to a halt, therefore creating a humangous solution is not an option.

Client projects have binary references to web-service binaries (it shouldn't, but it does). Sometimes I want not just debug, but to change code in those projects.

**Question**
Is there an easy way in Visual Studio (e.g. using an unknown to me R# feature, or a VS Power Toys extension or yet some other Visual Studio Extension/Plugin) to replace a binary reference with a project reference?